Mass defect and electron transition
According to the Special Theory of Relativity, $E=mc^2$.
When an electron and proton are independent (without influence of any kind of fields, especially electrostatic fields), their rest masses are $m_e$ and $m_p$. When they combine to form hydrogen atoms they emit photons. So there is some energy loss in the form of photons.
So, now mass of proton and electron in the hydrogen are $m_{eH}$ and $m_{pH}$. Why are $m_e$ and $m_p$ less than $m_{eH}$ and $m_{pH}$ ($m_e > m_{eH}, m_p > m_{pH}$)? So, the energy of photons is contributed by electrons as well as protons. Am I right or wrong?

Why are $m_e$ and $m_p$ less than $m_{eH}$ and $m_{pH}$ ($m_e > m_{eH}, m_p > m_{pH}$)? The English and the math are saying opposite things.

The rest energy of a hydrogen atom consists of the proton mass, the electron mass, the proton kinetic energy, the electron kinetic energy and the potential energy. In a bound state the negative potential energy overcomes the kinetic energy. The subatomic particle test masses remain the same.
